# Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?

Tags: sql, join

Qual é a diferença entre `INNER JOIN` e `OUTER JOIN`? Podem me dar alguns exemplos?

Answer (score 451, accepted):

### Uma breve explicação sobre Inner, Left, Right, Outer/Full e Cross Join

Vamos tomar por base estas duas tabelas:

[image: TabelaA e TabelaB]

Usando ambas em todos os exemplos, vamos ilustrar os tipos mais comuns de *join*.

## Inner Join

[image: Gráfico Inner Join]

Esse é um formato comum de join, que retorna dados apenas quando *as duas tabelas tem chaves correspondentes* na cláusula *ON* do join.

**Query:**

```sql
SELECT TabelaA.*, TabelaB.* FROM TabelaA INNER JOIN TabelaB ON TabelaA.Chave = TabelaB.Chave
```

**Resultado:**

[image: Inner Join]

## Left Join

[image: Gráfico Left Join]

É um dos formatos mais usados de *join*, que retorna a *Tabela A inteira* e *apenas os registros que coincidirem* com a igualdade do *join* na TabelaB (ou campos nulos para os campos sem correspondência).

**Query:**

```sql
SELECT TabelaA.*, TabelaB.* FROM TabelaA LEFT JOIN TabelaB ON TabelaA.Chave = TabelaB.Chave
```

**Resultado:**

[image: Left Join]

## Right Join

[image: Gráfico Right Join]

Tem exatos mesmos efeitos que o `Left Join`, o que muda é que a tabela que vai retornar tudo é a B em vez da A.

Basicamente a escolha entre Left e Right é de organização pessoal, dá para obter os mesmos resultados finais com as duas sintaxes, desde que inverta o lado das duas referências nas condições também.

**Query:**

```sql
SELECT TabelaA.*, TabelaB.* FROM TabelaA RIGHT JOIN TabelaB ON TabelaA.Chave = TabelaB.Chave
```

**Resultado:**

[image: Right Join]

## Full Outer Join

[image: Gráfico Full Outer Join]

Conhecida como `OUTER JOIN` ou simplesmente `FULL JOIN`, este retorna *todos os registros de ambas as tabelas*.

**Query:**

```sql
SELECT TabelaA.*, TabelaB.* FROM TabelaA FULL OUTER JOIN TabelaB ON TabelaA.Chave = TabelaB.Chave
```

**Resultado:**

[image: Full/Outer Join]

## Cross Join

[image: Gráfico Cross Join]

Basicamente é o produto cartesiano entre as duas tabelas. Para cada linha de TabelaA, são retornadas todas as linhas de TabelaB.

É mais fácil entender o Cross Join como um "Join sem cláusula ON", ou seja, todas as combinações de linhas de A e B são devolvidas.

Inclusive, se você fizer um Cross Join com cláusla ON, ele "vira" um mero Inner Join.

**Query:**

```sql
SELECT TabelaA.*, TabelaB.* FROM TabelaA CROSS JOIN TabelaB
```

Ou ainda:

```sql
SELECT TabelaA.*, TabelaB.* FROM TabelaA, TabelaB
```

**Resultado:**

[image: Cross Join]

## Considerações

Notar que todos os campos pedidos no *select* sempre retornam (desde que existam na tabela, obviamente), independente de existirem para aquela linha específica.

O que acontece no caso de uma linha ser retornada para apenas uma das tabelas é que os campos da outra vêm com conteúdo *null*.

Usualmente, caso você precise diferenciar um nulo que realmente exista na tabela de um nulo por falta de correspondência, basta ver se os campos usados na condição do `ON` não retornaram *null* também.

Comment: Eu já pesquisei sobre isso também por isso tenho salvo, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server, Note que como dito no primeiro comentaria, da resposta correta `LEFT JOIN` e `LEFT OUTER JOIN` são a mesma coisa.

Comment: Não contente em ter conseguido a primeira medalha de ouro "Ótima resposta" do site, você também acabou de levar a segunda com essa resposta. Parabéns! Só há duas dessas no site até agora e as duas são suas!

Comment: @VictorStafusa grato. Essa aqui é mais legal ver chegar nos 100, pq é desenvolvimento próprio, a outra foi mais o trabalho de tradução e adaptação. Mas tem outros colaboradores do site chegando nos 100 jajá pelo que eu andei vendo :)

Comment: algumas imagens foram retiradas, poderia editar e recolocar as imagens?

Comment: @V.Avancini as imagens retiradas eram versões anteriores das atuais, menos completas. Nada foi perdido, somente melhorei a diagramação e coloquei detalhes importantes em relação ao null  (tanto as anteriores quanto atuais fui eu quem produziu). Siga pelas atuais que a representação é muito melhor.

Answer (score 127):

Eu gosto de imagens para entender joins.

[image: TSQL join type]

Comment: tem algum exemplo de anti semi join com 3 tabelas?

Answer (score 52):

Inner join faz uma junção entre duas tabelas A e B onde a projeção serão todos os elementos de A que estão em B.

Ex.: Quero todos os clientes de um banco e suas determinadas agencias:

```
select * from Clientes inner join Agencias on Cliente.idAgencia = Agencias.idAgencia
```

Um outer join pode ser **Left**, **Rigth** e **Center (ou Cross)**.

Um left join faz uma junção entre A e B onde a projeção serão todos os elementos de A, independente se estão ou não em B.

Ex.: Quero todos os clientes do banco e a quantidade de movimentaçãoes efetuadas em abril de 2013:

```
select nomeCliente, count(idMovimentacao) from Clientes left outer join Movimentacoes on Clientes.idCliente = Movimentacoes.idCliente where Movimentacao.dtCompetencia = '04/2013'
```

Na query acima nós utilizamos o left join para que todos os clientes sejam impressos, mesmo que não tenham feito nenhuma movimentação.

O Rigth join é equivalente ao left join, mas com a ordem trocada.

O Center (Ou Cross) join cruza os dados de A e B, ou seja, imprime todos os elementos de A e os de B, independente de um estar ligado ao outro.

Ex.: Quero imprimir uma relação de Resutados de Analise Quimica de um determinado elemento e a data da analise.

```
select * from ResultadosAnalisesQuimicasElementos center join DatasAnalises on AnaliseQuimica.idAnalise = DatasAnalises.idAnalise
```

A consulta acima irá  imprimir todas as datas de analise juntamente com o resultado da analise quimica caso exista alguma analise associada à data em questão e Todas as analises juntamente com a data da analise em questão. Também serão impressas todas as datas em que não ocorreram analises e todos os elementos cujo não foram feitas nenhuma analise.

Segue abaixo um link com mais exemplos no [DevMedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/inner-cross-left-rigth-e-full-joins/21016)

Comment: E qual seria o JOIN que eu não seleciono as tuplas de B, independente de estarem ou não ligadas?

Comment: @Marconi WHAT?!

Answer (score 46):

Esta página é algo para ser impresso e colado na baia: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Basicamente, Clientes INNER JOIN Pedidos retorna apenas clientes que tenham feito pedidos.

Clientes OUTER JOIN Pedidos retorna clientes sem pedidos (as colunas de Pedidos estarão com NULL) e, se a integridade referencial não for imposta, pedidos sem clientes. Não muito útil.

Mais útil é Clientes LEFT JOIN Pedidos (também conhecido como LEFT OUTER JOIN) onde apenas clientes sem pedidos podem aparecer (mas não pedidos desirmanados de clientes).